# How to import data to a wide table in SQL server

Tags: database

I got a data import problem. I created a wide table in SQL server. 
And I want to import about 3000 rows data into the wide table. But the XML column is always with NULL.

Anybody can help ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more details to help folks understand the problem here? Is the XML column always expected to not be NULL? Or is it required to not be NULL?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that I have a csv file with 3000 columns. I want to use bulk insert to import data into the sql table. But the ordinary table is only allowed to have 1024 columns. So I try to use wide table to solve it. However, I cannot import data into the sparse column.

Comment: You ever figure it out? I'm having the same problem with a CSV I pulled from data.gov!